# Unable to deploy using SVN as Maven repo

Tags: svn, maven-2, version-control, maven-scm

I'm trying to use Subversion as Maven repo utilizing [Maven wagon](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-scm/). If I declare snapshot location using http as protocol I get 409 error back from server when trying to deploy (mvn clean deploy)

```
<snapshotRepository>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <id>engtools_snapshots</id>
        <name>EngTools Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://continuum.td.com/svn_repos/maven/snapshots</url>
</snapshotRepository>
```

When I change protocol to scm:svn:http things are getting even more weird - I get several errors seemingly related to realm

```
<snapshotRepository>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        <id>engtools_snapshots</id>
        <name>EngTools Maven Repository</name>
        <url>scm:svn:http://continuum.td.com/svn_repos/maven/snapshots</url>
</snapshotRepository>
```

SCM configuration

```
        <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-scm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-manager-plexus</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnexe</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```

Partial stacktrace resulting from (mvn deploy)

```
[INFO] [deploy:deploy {execution: default-deploy}]
[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from engtools_snapshots
[FATAL ERROR] org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo#execute() caused a 
linkage error (java.lang.AbstractMethodError) and may be out-of-date. Check 
the realms:
[FATAL ERROR] Plugin realm = 
app0.child-container[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4]
urls[0] = file:/C:/Documents and Settings/boo/.m2/repository/org/apache/
maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.4/maven-deploy-plugin-2.4.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Documents and Settings/boo/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/
plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[FATAL ERROR] Container realm = plexus.core
urls[0] = file:/C:/java/apache-maven-2.2.0/bin/../lib/maven-2.2.0-uber.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] org.apache.maven.scm.command.checkout.AbstractCheckOutCommand.
executeCheckOutCommand(Lorg/apache/maven/scm/provider/ScmProviderRepository;
Lorg/apache/maven/scm/ScmFileSet;Lorg/apache/maven/scm/ScmVersion;)
Lorg/apache/maven/scm/command/checkout/CheckOutScmResult;
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.maven.scm.command.checkout.AbstractCheckOutCommand.
executeCheckOutCommand(Lorg/apache/maven/scm/provider/ScmProviderRepository;
Lorg/apache/maven/scm/ScmFileSet;Lorg/apache/maven/scm/ScmVersion;)Lorg/apache/maven/scm/command/checkout/CheckOutScmResult;
 at org.apache.maven.scm.command.checkout.AbstractCheckOutCommand.executeCommand(
AbstractCheckOutCommand.java:49)
 at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:58)
```

Comment: Have you tried wiping ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins?

Comment: Yes - in fact I wiped whole local repo (.m2) few times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at wagon-scm's POM you'll see it has dependencies on the 1.0 versions of the maven-scm-provider-* artifacts. In your extensions section you've referenced the 1.3-SNAPSHOT versions.

From version 1.2 onwards, the AbstractCheckOutCommand's executeCheckOutCommand() method is no longer abstract, instead it delegates to another abstract method with an additional `recursive` parameter. Because of this change you get the linkage error.

The simplest way to remedy this is to change the versions of the maven-scm-provider-* extensions to be consistent with those required by wagon-scm, i.e. change the 1.3-SNAPSHOT versions for 1.0 or 1.1 versions.

It's worth pointing out I think that using an SCM system to host your Maven repository is not really a good idea, particularly for SNAPSHOT artifacts. Instead I'd recommend using a [repository manager](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix), they provide lots of useful features on top of hosting the artifacts.

Comment: Hi Rich,

Thanks for pointing this out, I will check it tomorrow and if works - will mark this as an accepted answer. I did look at the Artifactory as an option but that means yet another app server to maintain so I'll see how SCM solution will work

Comment: Glad to help, but I really would consider using a repository manager, you can even run Nexus or Artifactory standalone (they both use bundled Jetty) so no app server to manage

Comment: @Rich Seller: You overlook that the main obstacle to a repository manager is the “Pointy-Haired Boss” and “Mordac the Preventer of Information Services” and not the installation of an app server ;-) .